# Scrapy Item Not Defined

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm writing a crawler to get some pages from Yelp. I define the Yelp Item like this:

`yelpItem.py`:

```
import scrapy

class YelpItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    name = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
```

and in the spider folder, I use `YelpItem` in the `parse` function.

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//h3/span/a[contains(@class, "biz-name")]')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = YelpItem()
```

When running it, it says:

```
NameError: global name 'YelpItem' is not defined
```

I had searched several webpages, and tried to add codes like:

```
from hw1.items import YelpItem
```

(hw1 is my project name),but it is not helping. This will leads to an error like: `No module named items`

Can anyone help me to figure out how to deal with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
from hw1.yelpItem import YelpItem
```

Because when you try `from hw1.items` you are referencing to the `items.py` file but your `YelpItem` is in the `yelpItem.py` file you have to update the import path too.

You can read about the background why it is so [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though I solved it by change the item file's name back to items.py